# In Windows 10 Pro, Unable to save a file in C drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10

I got a new Windows 10 Pro laptop. When I tried to save a file in the C drive, I am getting Permission error. However, I am able to save a file in the Sub folder of c drive. And also , I am seeing an exclamation sign on the C drive.

What would be the reason ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UAC. Continue will work if your are member of the local administrator group, else you will got a permission error.

It's done to prevent unwanted program to save themselft anywhere on your harddisk

Comment: I couln't save a simple text file in the C drive

Comment: @goofyui are you a local admin?

Comment: i just bought a new laptop .. and its happening in my new laptop.. i am admin